# requestFileSystem throws SECURITY_ERR on Windows XP - Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

The following code is used in a Chrome application with the necesary permissions. It works ok in any operating system other than Windows XP.

```
    window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;     
    window.requestFileSystem(
        window.PERSISTENT, 
        1024*1024, 
        function(fs) {
            //...
        }, 
        function(e) {
            var msg = '';
            switch (e.code) {
                case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
                  msg = 'Quota exceeded.';
                  break;
                case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                  msg = 'Not found.';
                  break;
                case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
                  msg = 'Security error.';
                  break;
                case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
                  msg = 'Invalid modification.';
                  break;
                case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
                  msg = 'Invalid state.';
                  break;
                default:
                  msg = 'Unknown error.';
                  break;
            };              
            alert(msg);
        }
    );
```

Also, if you visit the filesystem example on HTM5Rocks.com, it throws the same errror under Windows XP: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

My current Google Chrome version is "13.0.782.220 m"

Comment: Are you sure that's the code? You're using `:` notation as a function parameter.

Comment: This seems to also happen with Chrome is in incognito mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you've just faced with this webkit bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94314

Comment: No, the Windows account username is "usuario"

Comment: Yes, definitively my bug is related to issue 94314.
My user doesn't have latin characters but my local path does.
You were right. It is a bug on Chrome when there is a latin character in the user path. The user data directory under Windows XP Spanish version has latin characters by default:
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Configuración local\Datos de programa\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\File System\

Answer (score 0):

Also check that you are running the page on a web server?

This throws the SECURITY_ERR for me:

```
file:///Sites/cordova-files/platforms/browser/www/index.html
```

But this doesn't:

```
http://localhost:8888/cordova-files/www/
```